# Multiple users at login

Tags: php

Please how to let every user log into his own area ?
I don't want to the users to join "thecommonplace"
I want them to be logged into their respective areas
Like for example : 
anna => site.com/anna/
mike => site.com/mike/
that's what I want and I have no idea how to do it correctly

require('db.php');
  session_start();

```
if (isset($_POST['uname']))
{

    $uname = stripslashes($_REQUEST['uname']); 
    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$uname); 

    $pwd = stripslashes($_REQUEST['pwd']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$pwd);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uname='$uname' and pwd='$pwd'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysql_error());

    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($rows == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
        // I don't want to the users to join "thecommonplace"
        // I want them to be logged into their respective areas
        // Like for example : 
        // anna => site.com/anna/
        // mike => site.com/mike/
        // that's what I want and I have no idea how to do it correctly
        header("Location: site.com/thecommonplace/"); 
    }
        else
        {
        // no such user
        }
}

else // present login form
{
```

Comment: `header("Location: site.com/$uname/");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it! All you need to do is instead of hard coding the link, just add the `$uname` behind it. You can stick strings together using `.`
so your header line would be like this

`header("Location: site.com/" . $uname);`

```
require('db.php'); session_start();

if (isset($_POST['uname']))
{

$uname = stripslashes($_REQUEST['uname']); 
$uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$uname); 

$pwd = stripslashes($_REQUEST['pwd']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$pwd);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uname='$uname' and pwd='$pwd'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysql_error());

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($rows == 1)
{
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
    // I don't want to the users to join "thecommonplace"
    // I want them to be logged into their respective areas
    // Like for example : 
    // anna => site.com/anna/
    // mike => site.com/mike/
    // that's what I want and I have no idea how to do it correctly
    header("Location: site.com/" . $uname); 
}
    else
    {
    // no such user
    }
}
```

Comment: Incredible. So logical. Works like a charm. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try This `Location: site.com/$uname/`

```
  if($rows == 1)
        {
            $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
            header("Location: site.com/$uname/"); 
        }
            else
            {
            // no such user
            }
```